# spring batch itemreader read chunk size to 1000 lines

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have an inbound job which reads file from one source folder and writes in to the database, tested with 500 lines in the file, job is run fine and with 'Completed status' and I could see all the 500 records in to the database table. However when I ran with 1000 lines (all 1000 records are valid) in the file and it run fine and with 'Completed status' but I could see only 500 records in to the database table.

Some thing like `commit-interval` I need to specify.

The question is why the job is skipping rest of the 500 records without committing to the database when I run the job with 1000 records.

**here is the configuration.**

```
<batch:job id="job">
    <batch:step id="step1"
        parent="jobMainStep1”>
</batch:step>
    </batch:job>
<batch:step id="
        jobMainStep1 " abstract="true">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk commit-interval="500" reader="jobNewReader"
                processor="jobHoldingTankItemProcessor" writer="jobClassifierReportWriter">
                <batch:streams>
                    <batch:stream ref="itemWriter433" />
                    <batch:stream ref="itemWriter233" />
                    <batch:stream ref="itemWriter633" />
                </batch:streams>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="jobInPageHeaderCallback" />
            <batch:listener ref="jobInPageFooterCallback" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
    ...
```

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: Can you add job configuration, classes, etc? the question is not clear enough

Comment: Added the configuration xml